# Container command fails when deploying

Tags: python, django, configuration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my Django project using Elastic Beanstalk. It's been fine until it tried to run container commands.
Here's my .config file looks like:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  02_createsuperuser: # <- The error occurs here
    command: "echo \"from account.models import Account; Account.objects.create_superuser('Me', 'Me', 'myemail@gmail.com', 'superadmin', 'MyPassword')\" | python3 manage.py shell"
```

And my cfn.init file logs this error:

```
[ERROR] Command 02_createsuperuser (echo "from account.models import Account; Account.objects.create_superuser('Me', 'Me', 'myemail@gmail.com', 'superadmin', 'MyPassword')" | python3 manage.py shell) failed
2021-12-06 03:22:18,662 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of postbuild_0_package404: Command 02_createsuperuser failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 573, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 273, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 02_createsuperuser failed
2021-12-06 03:22:18,665 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2021-12-06 03:22:18,665 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 02_createsuperuser failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 176, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 135, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 561, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 573, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 273, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 02_createsuperuser failed
```

How can I fix this issue? I'll try to provide further information if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Tried this and worked :D

```
02_createsuperuser:
  command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && and so on..."
```